# Setting published app domain and appname in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angularjs ui-router with this stateProvider:

```
.state("admin", {
           abstract:true,
           url: "/admin",
           templateUrl: "/app/template/adminabstract.html",
           controller: "AdminAbstractController"
       })
         .state("admin.view1", {
             url: "/view1",
             templateUrl: "/app/template/adminview1.html",
             controller: "AdminView1Controller"
         }).state("admin.view2", {
             url: "/view2",
             templateUrl: "/app/template/adminview2.html",
             controller: "AdminView2Controller"
         })
```

Here is the current localhost link:

http://localhost:52058/index.html#/admin/view2

It works just fine in localhost, however when I publish to the server it no longer works. Here is what the link looks like on the server:

http://specific.com/appname/otheridentifier/index.html#/admin/view2

For my app to work when it is published I think I need to change my ui-router config or state provider so my localhost is

http://localhost:52058/index.html#/appname/otheridentifier/admin/view2

Am I on the right track? What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: is your website in the root of "specific.org" or in a subdirectory

Comment: It is in a subdirectory:

Answer (score 0):

Since your website doesn't look like its in the root of the site you cant do

```
templateUrl: "/app/template/adminview1.html"
```

the / is saying look at the root of this website so it looks at

```
http://specific.org/app/template
```

you would want to change your template address to

```
templateUrl: "/appname/otheridentifier/app/template/adminview1.html"
```

Comment: If I change the templateUrl won't the /index.html#/ be missing from the final link?  It would be something like: http://specific.com/appname/otheridentifier/index.html#/appname/otheridentifier/app/template/adminview1.html

Comment: the /index.html#/ is not necessary. 
/index.html#/ is exactly the same as /#/